# Image HTTP upload in C++ is corrupted

Tags: php, c++, http, winsock

I was trying to upload a PNG image using Windows sockets HTTP to a PHP script.  Everything seems to work fine, but when I try to open my image in Windows Paint, I get an error message:

> This is not a valid bitmap file.

I don't know what is wrong.  I am a bit new to HTTP header fields so I my guess is that the header may be wrong.  What could be causing this?

The C++ code ([original C++ pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/VREQpVy4)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "windows.h"
#include "stdio.h"

using namespace std;

#define PORT       80
#define IP         "127.0.0.1"
#define HOST       "locahost"
#define RECEIVER   "/up.php"
#define COMPNAME   "compname"
#define PROGRAM    "program"
#define FILENAME   "file"
#define BOUNDARY   "----------boundary"
#define DUMMY_DATA "c2FzYXNhc2FzZGRmZGZkY2Q="
#define DUMMY_FILE "ok.png"

//------------------------------------
string constructBody(string args[2], string file[2]);
string readFile(string fileName);
//------------------------------------

int main() {
    // initiate the socket!
    SOCKET dataSock;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int error = WSAStartup(0x0202, &wsaData);
    if (error != 0) {
        WSACleanup();
        exit(1);  // oh shit, this shouldn't happen!
    }
    // all internets, engage!
    SOCKADDR_IN target;
    target.sin_family = AF_INET;
    target.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    target.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP);
    dataSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (dataSock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        exit(1); // Houston, we have a problem!
    }
    connect(dataSock, (SOCKADDR*)&target, sizeof(target));

    string programNames[5][2] = {{"Browser", "Mozilla"}};
    string file[2] = {FILENAME, "Default.txt"};

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        printf("Sending data for %s\n", (programNames[i][1]).c_str());
        string body = constructBody(programNames[i], file);
        char header[1024];
        sprintf(header, "POST %s HTTP 1.1\r\n"
                        "Host: %s\r\n"
                        "Content-Length: %d\r\n"
                        "Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n"
                        "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=%s\r\n"
                        "\r\n", RECEIVER, IP, strlen(body.c_str()), BOUNDARY);
//        printf("%s\n\n", header);
        int p = send(dataSock, header, strlen(header), 0);
//        printf("p == %d\n", p);
        int k = send(dataSock, body.c_str(), strlen(body.c_str()), 0);
//        printf("k == %d\n", k);

      char buff[1024];
      recv(dataSock, buff, 1024, 0);
      printf("%s\n\n", buff);
    }

    closesocket(dataSock);
    WSACleanup();
}

string readFile(string fileName) {
    string fileContents;
    ifstream tmp(fileName.c_str());
    getline(tmp, fileContents);
    tmp.close();

    return fileContents;
}

string constructBody(string args[2], string file[2]) {
    string body;
    string CRLF = "\r\n";

    // first we add the args
    body.append("--"+string(BOUNDARY)+CRLF);
    body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\""+string(COMPNAME)+"\""+CRLF);
    body.append(CRLF);
    body.append(args[0]+CRLF);
    body.append("--"+string(BOUNDARY)+CRLF);
    body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\""+string(PROGRAM)+"\""+CRLF);
    body.append(CRLF);
    body.append(args[1]+CRLF);

    // now we add the file
    body.append("--"+string(BOUNDARY)+CRLF);
    body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\""+string(FILENAME)+"\"; filename=\""+string(DUMMY_FILE)+"\""+CRLF);
    body.append("Content-Type: media-type"+CRLF);
    body.append(CRLF);
    body.append(DUMMY_DATA+CRLF);
    body.append("--"+string(BOUNDARY)+"--"+CRLF);
    body.append(CRLF);

//    printf(body.c_str()); exit(0);

    return body;
}
```

The PHP code ([original PHP pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/cNX4duHy)):

```
<?php
/* ===== CONSTANTS ===== */
$ROOT_DIR = 'FILES';
$COMPUTER_NAME = 'compname';
$PROGRAM = 'program';
$FILENAME = 'file';
$CHUNK_SIZE = 1024;
/* ===================== */

//=====================================
/**
    Function that gets current time and formats it into pretty looking date
*/
function makeDate() {
    return strftime('%Y-%m-%d, %H.%M');
}
//=====================================
// check here if the parameters are set. If it's not then it's safe to say some one is snooping around...
 if (isset($_POST[$COMPUTER_NAME], $_POST[$PROGRAM], $_FILES[$FILENAME])) {
    // construct a full path and create it
    $fullPath = $ROOT_DIR.'\\'.$_POST[$COMPUTER_NAME].'\\'.$_POST[$PROGRAM].'\\'.makeDate();
    mkdir($fullPath, 0777, true);

    // move the files and rename them as temporary
    $filename = $_FILES[$FILENAME]['name'];
    move_uploaded_file(($_FILES[$FILENAME]['tmp_name']), $fullPath.'\\'.$filename.'.tmp');

    // decode received files
    $src = fopen($fullPath.'\\'.$filename.'.tmp', 'rb');
    $dst = fopen($fullPath.'\\'.$filename, 'wb');
    while (!feof($src)) {
        fwrite($dst, base64_decode(fread($src, $CHUNK_SIZE)));
    }
    fclose($dst);
    fclose($src);
    unlink($fullPath.'\\'.$filename.'.tmp'); // remove the temp file after decoding it

    echo 'OK!';
} else {
    echo 'oh no :(';
}
//=====================================
?>
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the very least, the C++ code is reading the .png file as a text file, and treating the contents as a null-terminated string.  It also seems to be reading only up to the first line ending.  What you want to do is a binary read of the .png file.

Try changing your `readFile()` function to use the same binary read capability as this [example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/).

Note that in the example, the file size is read first, in order to allocate an adequately-sized buffer.  You may not want to deal with buffer management manually, so you can choose to use a `vector<char>` instead, and the associated memory resource will be allocated/released for you.  Refer to this [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for the reference guide for `vector<>`.

Something like this may be closer to what you want:

```
bool readFile(string fileName, vector<char> &fileContents) {
    vector<char> fileContents;
    std::ifstream is (fileName.c_str(), std::ifstream::binary);
    bool success = is;

    if (success) {
        // get length of file:
        is.seekg (0, is.end);
        int length = is.tellg();
        is.seekg (0, is.beg);

        fileContents.resize(length);
        is.read(fileContents, length);
        is.close();
    }

    return success;
}
```

With these changes, you'll have to change how you call `readFile()`.  It's interesting to note is that `readFile()` is never actually called in the code that you posted, so there will be a point in `constructBody()` in which you declare a `fileContents` variable and call `readFile()` to populate it.

Consider this use of `readFile()`:

```
vector<char> fileContents;
bool success = readFile(filename, fileContents);
```

Later in the same function, you'll want to output the `fileContents` to the `body` buffer.

As with `fileContents`, the `body` variable should not be a `string`, so as to avoid the incidental null-termination.  It's better to use a `vector<char>` in this instance, as well, and all of the calls to `body.append()` will need to be updated to properly append the content and line endings.  It should be straightforward, but will still require some additional work to complete.

I have not delved into the PHP code, as this is going to be the first major issue that you have with reading and sending the .png file.  Whether it's something else, entirely.  You will want to make sure that the content of the file received by the PHP code matches the actual contents of the original .png file, and you can provide debugging output to do that.  Until they match, it's likely still an issue in the C++ code.